# Apache log analyzer for bandwidth usage?

Tags: apache-2.2, bandwidth, logging

I'm running a server that hosts several different websites and content.  I want to know which websites and which files or services are using up the bandwidth.  Do any of the freeware apache log analyzers do this?

For example, it would be nice to know amount of bandwidth consumed per different URL ever requested from the server.

Answer (score 7):

[awstats](http://awstats.sourceforge.net) includes the total bandwidth of each entry in every hit-count statistic it reports. So you get bandwidth per day, per month, per hour of the day, per country, per client IP, per URL, etc.  The bandwidth amounts may not be dead-on accurate since they're computed from the Apache log's recorded transfer size, which doesn't include every single byte sent over the network (things like the internals of a TCP packet aren't included), but they're pretty close. Just don't rely on awstats (or any logfile analyzer) to tell you when you're hitting your hosting provider's bandwidth cap ;-)

Answer (score 0):

[webalizer](http://www.mrunix.net/webalizer/) should do the trick, at least for n most popular urls and total transfer.

Comment: It does look awfully ugly though. :)